# Python - Add matched square bracket with numbers regular expression to 2d Array

Tags: python, regex, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write some python to parse through a text log. There is a time stamp on most lines in the log, and if the log contains certain text, I would like to capture the time stamps in a 2d array so that I can later compare a value to the values in the 2d array.

An example log file looks like:

```
[1542053213 s] Starting Program TEE:
-----------------------------------------
[1542053213 s] PROGRAM ERROR
ERRHAND: 1033
ERRHAND: 233545
ERRHAND: 1
[1542053213 s] Program completed!

[1542053300 s] Ending Program. Stopping!


[1542053500 s] Starting Program FOO:
-----------------------------------------
[1542060100 s] Program completed!   

[1542060105 s] Ending Program. Stopping!
```

My code currently is able to appropriately detect the start and stop lines:

```
from os.path import expanduser
import re

#Setting variables
filepath = expanduser('~/LogAutomation/programlog.txt')
timeArray = []
tempStart = ''
tempEnd = ''

with open(filepath) as myFile:
    line = myFile.readline()
    cnt = 1
    while line:
        if ("Starting Program") in line:
            print("MATCH FOUND FOR STARTING PROGRAM")
            print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
            #Add timestamp to time array
                #tempStart = matched regular expression

        elif ("Ending Program. Stopping!") in line:
            print("MATCH FOUND FOR ENDING PROGRAM")
            print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
            #Add timestamp to time array
                #tempEnd = matched regular expression

        #Add [tempStart, tempEnd] to timeArray

        line = myFile.readline()
        cnt +=1

myFile.close()

print("Completed Script")
```

However, I am trying to add the commented functionality. I am not sure where to begin to do so. I have tried using https://pythex.org/ in order to create a regular expression and am trying to edit the following in order to extract the number sequence out of the [digits(space)s] sequence: `(\[[,\d]*)` but it is not matching the example timestamps in the log above. It is currently including the beginning bracket, which I don't want.

Any assistance with determining how to extract the digits, and add items to the 2d array, would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE:  I am a brand new Python developer so please excuse me if this is an easy problem. I am trying quickly to learn.

EDIT ---
Here is an updated code base using a suggestion below:

```
from os.path import expanduser
import re

#Setting variables
filepath = expanduser('~/LogAutomation/programlog.txt')
timeArray = []
tempStart = ''
tempEnd = ''

# with open(filepath) as myFile:
#     line = myFile.readline()
#     cnt = 1
#     while line:
#         if ("Starting Program") in line:
#             print("MATCH FOUND FOR STARTING PROGRAM")
#             print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
#             #Add timestamp to time array
#                 #tempStart = matched regular expression
#
#         elif ("Ending Program. Stopping!") in line:
#             print("MATCH FOUND FOR ENDING PROGRAM")
#             print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
#             #Add timestamp to time array
#                 #tempEnd = matched regular expression
#
#         #Add [tempStart, tempEnd] to timeArray
#
#         line = myFile.readline()
#         cnt +=1
#
# myFile.close()

import re

with open(filepath) as myFile:
    all_logs = myFile.read()
    starting_regex = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\s+s\]\s+Starting\s+Program')
    ending_regex = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\s+s\]\s+Ending\s+Program\.\s+Stopping')

    start_times = list(map(int, starting_regex.findall(all_logs)))
    end_times = list(map(int, ending_regex.findall(all_logs)))

    timeArray = list(map(list, zip(start_times, end_times)))

    for x in timeArray:
        print(x)
        print(timeArray[x])

print("Completed Script")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first create a regex for Starting Program:

```
\[(\d+)\s+s\]\s+Starting\s+Program
```

This is just a simple regex which will match strings like `[1542053213 s] Starting Program`.

But if you notice, I have added a pair of parenthesis with `\d+` (the digits part), adding the parenthesis makes it a group in the regex, and this is the only group we have in this regex.

Similarly, I will create a regex for Ending Program, making the digits a group:

```
\[(\d+)\s+s\]\s+Ending\s+Program\.\s+Stopping
```

Now, let's use them in a python program, and pick the groups:

```
import re

with open(filepath) as myFile:
    all_logs = myFile.read()
    starting_regex = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\s+s\]\s+Starting\s+Program')
    ending_regex = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\s+s\]\s+Ending\s+Program\.\s+Stopping')

    start_times = list(map(int, starting_regex.findall(all_logs)))
    end_times = list(map(int, ending_regex.findall(all_logs)))

    timeArray = list(map(list, zip(start_times, end_times)))
```

In the program above, I have read all of the log file at once, and used `findall` method to find all of the occurrences in the `all_logs` that the regex will match.

Now, the interesting part is: `findall` only returns the list of values matching to groups, and we only have one group in the regex, which is `(\d+)`, so, `start_times` and `end_times` will just contain the time values.

The corresponding values of `start_times` and `end_times` contain the time of starting program and ending program.

So, to make a pair of each, let's just `zip` both lists. It will create `tuple`s of each of the pair, and let's just convert each `tuple` to `list` using `map` method, and then convert the `map` object to `list` to make a list of lists.

`timeArray` will be a list of lists now. Each sub-list containing only two elements, first being the starting time of program, and second being the ending time.

*Edit*:

You don't actually need a loop to print out the values of `timeArray`. You can just use a `print` statement to see the values, it'll print the entire list:

```
print(timeArray)
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Ahmad. I appreciate your response and how detailed you were. I really like this approach.

I tried implementing your code and adding in a loop to print out timeArray but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. How can I see the values? Later, I will be comparing a value to the values in timeArray.

Comment: Can you post your current code in the question, so I can have a look?

Comment: @JerryM. I have edited my answer. Tell me if you have any more of troubles.

Comment: Unfortunately, timeArray prints as empty.

Comment: @JerryM. for testing, try printing `all_logs` and see whether the data has been read successfully or not. Because I ran this code with a sample log string that you provided, and it's working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To capture just the digits, you need to put only the characters matching the digits between the parentheses, like so: `(\d+)`

To match the full square bracket at the beginning, with the space (`\s` denotes a whitespace character): `\[(\d+)\s`

If you want to be even more specific (while still only capturing digits) by matching the full time stamp up to the closing square bracket: `\[(\d+) s\]`, where the space between the `)` paren and the `s` is significant.

The complete regex expression (assuming the use of `.match()`) could then be:

```
regex = "\[(\d+)\s"
tempStart = re.match(regex, line).group(1)
```

To put the values in a 2d array, you're right in that `[tempStart, tempEnd]` basically forms a row. To add this to `timeArray`, we can use:

```
timeArray.append([tempStart, tempEnd])
```

Comment: Hi @Carol Ng thank you for the answer.
I appreciate you pointing out the append method.
However, for the regex, I am mainly concerned with just capturing the numeric value inside the bracket, not the whitespace or the character s. How can I just grab the value inside the bracket? `(\d+)` returns other digits in the log file that are not enclosed in the bracket.

Comment: @JerryM. I amended my answer to include some more specific regexes, including the starting and ending square brackets.

Comment: I just attempted to implement your suggested `\[(\d+) s\]` solution and it is still returning the brackets, space, and s character. I am interested in returning only the digits encapsulated in the brackets. Might you have a suggestion on how to extract just the "time" or digits?

Comment: @JerryM. Depending on the regex matching method you're using, there are different ways to capture the text between the parens. If you're using `.match()`, you'll need to call it like so: `.match().group(1)` to get the digits. If you're using `.findall()`, the captured group will be somewhere in the returned array.